# Get some elements from array on json data type postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table "products" which have multi columns, on of these column "specifications" is json and I have this data on it:

```
[
        {
            "en":"Weight",
            "ar":"الوزن",
            "value":"100"
        },
        {
            "en":"Height",
            "ar":"الارتفاع",
            "value":"300"
        }
    ]
```

I need to get only "en, value" or "ar, value" from this field in addition to remain fields of the table.

Comment: If your is a "classic" relational DBMS (you don't specify if you are using or not NoSQL extension of postgres, and I assume not) the only solution I see is to get that values and manually parse them

Comment: It seems as you mentioned. I have to parse it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try this

```
select column_names,
 --all column names you can left "specifications" column
(select string_agg(v,',') from
(select '(' || (val->>'en')::text || ',' || (val->>'value')::text || ')' as v 
    --You can put whatever json key-value you want here 
 from (select value as val from
(select value from json_array_elements("specifications"))))) from "products"
```

hope it works for you.

Comment: You can refer [Json in PostgrSql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html) for more details